# Print the lambda passed to a Func object

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I can print a lambda expression like this

```
Expression<Func<double,double>> expr = x => x * x; 
string s = expr.ToString(); // "x => (x * x)"
```

However if

```
Func<double, double> function = x => x * x;
```

Then how can I generate the `Expression<Func<double,double>>` to produce the same result ? Expression constructor is internal and there is no implicit conversion between Func types and Expression of them.

Comment: You can't. When you do `Expression<...> expr = x => ...`, the C# compiler emits code which constructs that expression tree at runtime. When you do `Func<...> f = x => ...`, the compiler emits code which actually does the thing you asked, and throws away all of the information required to create an Expression.

Comment: Can I ask WHY you want to do this?  Is it some sort of debugging support?

Comment: @Neil : I thought it have been neat to be able to display to unit test explorer the math expression (or the closest thing) of the input (Func argument initialized by a lambda) when unit testing a calculus module. To distinguish between NUnit test cases more easily (NUnit just .ToString the args in the test case name when you use the TestCase attribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

When you write:

```
Expression<Action<int>> e = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
```

The compiler emits (simplified):

```
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
MethodInfo method = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(object) });
MethodCallExpression body = Expression.Call(null, method, parameterExpression);
Expression<Action<int>> e = Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(body, parameterExpression);
```

See how it actually emits code which re-creates the expression tree at runtime?

In contrast, when you write:

```
Action<int> a = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
```

The compiler emits (simplified)

```
internal void GeneratedMethod(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

...

Action<int> a = new Action<int>(GeneratedMethod);
```

See the difference? The runtime simply isn't able to take a compiled method and create an expression tree for it.

The only way that expression trees get constructed is using the methods on the `Expression` class to build it up out of its various parts. If you use a lambda, the compiler cleverly emits code which does this at runtime. However you can't start with a *compiled* method.

See the examples on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4AEBMBGAsAKHQAYACdbAOgBlYBHCgUQA8AHAJwFMBnLqAexhcA3AXQBmMphIBhEgG8CJJWQnoALDM4QALt3KYAFAEpFyhfmWWy2TAB5Y2gHwkIJALwkm75+QCcBpiMRC2UAX1MlCJUyDWktXS5mdm5eAWMo8ytlJM4efhhbfXsYJ2cOd09va39A4Mtw/AagA).